# How to start the JMS provider in WSO2 IoT server

Tags: wso2

I have downloaded the necessitated `jars` as mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/JMS+Transport) in `$CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib` folder. I am getting the following error

```
Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the complete answer on my [blog post](https://medium.com/@smartsplash/setting-up-jms-queue-in-wso2-iot-server-f20991821366)